# Are frugal students going to get reimbursed as a part of student loan forgiveness?

Tags: united-states, student-loan

I have always been a frugal student. I took extra part time jobs and paid for my college. Never took a loan. Now with a great pain in my heart I realize that all of my efforts were in vain. I could have taken the damn loan, and Biden would forgive it all.

I remember my classmates who were taking federal loans and focusing on study. I on the other hand was a idiot not to take advantage of the student loans. REGRET!!! Now Biden is going to forgive all those easy going students with loans, and I feel like an idiot.

I feel like I’m being punished for being extra frugal, sitting on beans and rice all these years. Damn. I should have taken a loan, and eat whatever I wanted. Punishment for being extra responsible.

Does Biden’s proposal include reimbursing students who paid money for their tuition?

Comment: The question in the title asks us to predict the future (and is opinion-based depending on what you consider "frugal"), whereas the question in the body asks about what is included in a proposal by the President. Neither of these is really on-topic, and the rest of the content just sounds like a complaint that other people may get some benefit that doesn't apply to you.

Comment: If this were less ranty it might fit on [politics.se] but I don't know

Comment: Just think yourself lucky you are no longer living in a country presided over by a narcissistic maniac intent on taking you, your compatriots, and the world, to hell in a handbasket. That should outweigh whatever grievance you think you have.

Comment: Just so you know, this is a bad reason to oppose something. It's like opposing ending the death penalty, because ending it now wouldn't bring back the people who were already executed.

Comment: The realistic answer is almost certainly "You'll get screwed"  :/

Comment: @user253751 - in Britain, this very argument was put forward to the Royal Commission on Capital Punishment (1949-1953). A retired senior judge said if hanging were abolished it would be "unfair" to all the people who had been previously executed. Nobody asked him if he thought that burning at the stake should therefore be re-introduced. Capital punishment was abolished in 1964.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is off topic for this stack.

The issue itself is problematic for the very reasons you state. And many that you don't.
First - How to separate the needy from those who aren't? Does the student from the wealthy family who just graduated business school with loans but with a $100K/yr job get the same debt cancellation? I feel similar to you, only I am the parent. I (We) made a choice. Instead of putting the funds into our retirement acct or paying off the mortgage, we set money aside to pay our daughter's education in full. Graduating this spring.

In discussion forums I proposed a more reasoned approach - payment required are based on income of the graduate. Say, 10% of the income over $50,000. (this is just an example, a starting point). A graduate with lower income isn't burdened by that month's payment, nor does interest accrue. That month is credited/ written off. The low wage worker avoids the feeling of crushing debt, the high wage earner has a reasonable payment, $5K/year if he makes $100K/yr. The term is 20 years, both to spread the 'forgiveness' part out over time, but also to allow people to see their wages rise and participate in a fair payback if/when that occurs.

There is a huge elephant in the room as far as college education goes. We have an imbalance in the jobs available for them. Last I checked government data, nearly 2/3 of jobs forecasting growth in the next decade do not require a degree. Healthcare aides (those who work in a nursing home or memory care facility to take care of us when we get old) in general do not require a full college degree. Not are they paid a decent wage. This issue can't be separated from the fight for a $15 minimum wage. i.e. If we, as a society, declare we wish to get to a 50% college educated population, we need to compensate workers in the highest 50% of jobs to make that degree valuable.

Last - money isn't unlimited. My budget reflects my priorities. My daughter's education, the charities I support, etc. The national budget isn't unlimited either. (Clearly, my opinion that) We should prioritize how we spend. Healthcare - are people still dying from lack of insulin? This is the cheapest dollars/life saved thing to do. Hunger - should we not put this ahead of cancelling debt wholesale? Poverty. All of these issues have been with us for far too long, and should be prioritized. The debt cancellation feels like a distraction to me, with far more pressing issue to address.

Comment: If you believe the question is off-topic, why did you answer it?

Comment: Uncontrollable immature impulse. Because for the rest of the day, in a room with teenagers, I will need to throttle the urge to speak my mind, and must act like the adult they think I am. (What part of "you can't eat in the classroom" wasn't clear on that huge sign?) If I were a bit more mature, I'd delete Michael's comment, but I'll leave that for a fellow mod.

Comment: Understood, I’ve been there. You are doing the Lord’s work teaching math to our future. Thank you for your service. :) +1, BTW.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica - maybe I'm tempting fate, but it's still there, and has got 2 upvotes now.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Biden’s proposal include reimbursing students who paid money for their tuition?

Since March 20, 2020, federal student loans have been at 0% interest, and payments are not required. This has been extended by executive order through September 30, 2021. (Source: [studentaid.gov](https://studentaid.gov/announcements-events/coronavirus))

Anything other than that is only a proposal and subject to change. [Nerdwallet published an article dated February 4, 2021](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/loans/student-loans/joe-biden-student-loans) that outlines some of the proposals that have been suggested by the Biden administration. None of them that I can see suggest any type of aid for students/graduates that funded their educations in a way other than federal student loans.

Comment: Forgiving student loan is a slap in the face for responsible people